# sizeof the class in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

The size of of the classes as follow while using virtual inheritance..

```
ABase=4(sizeof imem)
BBase=12(sizeof imem+ABase+VBase_ptr)
CBase=12(sizeof imem+ABase+VBase_ptr)
```

This is justified, but i do not understand why the size of `ABCDerived` is 24.

```
class ABase{ 
        int iMem; 
}; 

class BBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 

class CBase : public virtual ABase { 
        int iMem; 
}; 

class ABCDerived : public BBase, public CBase { 
        int iMem; 
};
```

Comment: Although these details are implementation dependent it's likely due to how it adds and arranges offset tables.

Comment: Tell us what you think it should be instead, and why. Then we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6876955/2485710 you are also not specifying if you are on a 32 bit machine or a 64 bit one, the fact that you are compiling a 32 bit executable is an educated guess in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is going to be extremely platform-dependant, but I think we can understand what's going on.

First off, the Standard doesn't specify how virtual inheitence is to be implemented.  As far as the Standard is concerned, there's not even any such thing as a vtable.

`ABCDerived` has `BBase` and `CBase` Each of which is comprised of an `int`.  There is also a single instance of `ABase` which is comprised of an `int`.  Finally there is a vtable ptr.

The size of an `int` is platform dependant -- it's not necesarrily 4 bytes.  But if we assume it is 4 bytes, and the size of the vtable is also 4 bytes, we have:

```
int  [ABCDerived] = 4 bytes
int  [CBase]      = 4 bytes
int  [BBase]      = 4 bytes
int  [ABase]      = 4 bytes
vtable            = 4 bytes
                 -------------
                   20 bytes
```

That doesn't mean the `sizeof (ABCDerived)` is 20 however.  Alignment comes in to play here as well.  The Standard allows compilers to increase the size of an object so that the size is divisible by a number of whole words.

Consider:

```
class ABase{ 
            int iMem; 
}; 

class BBase : public virtual ABase { 
            int iMem; 
}; 

class CBase : public virtual ABase { 
            int iMem; 
}; 

class ABCDerived : public BBase, public CBase { 
            int iMem; 
}; 

int main()
{
    ABCDerived d;
    BBase& b = d;
    ABase* ab = &b; 
    CBase& c = d;
    ABase* ac = &b; 

    cout << hex << (void*) ab << "\n"
        << hex << (void*) ac << "\n";

    cout << sizeof (d) << "\n" << sizeof (int) << "\n";
}
```

The output is `28` on my 64 bit Linux machine.

However if I turn on packing (using a platform-dependant #pragma switch):

```
#pragma pack (1)
```

The output is now 20.

So, the long and the short of all this is:

There is a ton of platform-dependant stuff going on here.  You can't say the size of the object is this or that, at least without employing more platform-dependant stuff and knowing how your compiler actually implements virtual inheritence.  The size of it is whatever the size of it is.

Comment: @YSBhai: I say it's platform dependent.

Comment: @YSBhai: I'd say that a few spaces could help understanding the output

Answer (score 0):

**Size should be 20**, As you used virtual inheritance ABCDerived wont inherit ABase IMem twice. As you are telling it is giving 24, May be virtual inheritance is not supporting by your compiler.

Comment: Not necesarrily.  Yopu are close though, so I reverted.